# Make hr element clear:both in CKEditor edit window

Tags: css, drupal, ckeditor

I am adding content in a CKEditor 4 window and I have an hr element that is not clearing content to its left:

[image: CKEditor window screenshot]

How can I update the css used in the window so that hr tags have the `clear: both;` property?

I've tried adding the standard

```
hr {
    clear: both;
}
```

property in my own less, as well as nesting it within ckeditor classes, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The `hr` tag is meant to create a "paragraph-level thematic break", it's not for clearing. Also you can add a `div` element after the `hr` tag with the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

  .clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

.clearfix {display: inline-block;}  /* for IE/Mac */

</style><!-- main stylesheet ends, CC with new stylesheet below... -->

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
  .clearfix {
    zoom: 1;     /* triggers hasLayout */
    display: block;     /* resets display for IE/Win */
   }  /* Only IE can see inside the conditional comment
         and read this CSS rule. Don't ever use a normal HTML
         comment inside the CC or it will close prematurely. */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html). Hope that helps.